# Passiv "sein" und "werden "

Tags: grammaticality, passive

Ich habe eine Frage zu einem Thema, das ich gerade gelernt habe. Beispiel:

> Ihre Bestellung ist verschickt. → Passiv und "Action is already done"
>   Ihre Bestellung wird bearbeitet. → Passiv und "Action is happening"

Und zwar ist meine Frage: Ich lese oft die Beispielesätze in Wörterbüchern. Z. B.:

> erschlagen = vom Blitz **erschlagen werden**

Ist das auch Passiv? Wenn ja, kann man das Folgende so sagen?

> Ein Mann wird vom Blitz erschlagen. – A man is being hit by lightening. → still in action
>   Ein Mann ist vom Blitz erschlagen. – A man is hit by lightening. → action is done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Erstens**

Ja, das ist auch Passiv.

**Zweitens**

> Ihre Bestellung ist verschickt => Passiv und "Action is already done"

Das ist nicht ganz richtig.

Auch beim Passiv gibt es eine Vergangenheitsform:

> Ihre Bestellung **wurde** verschickt.

Bedeutet:

> Your order **has been** shipped.

Als Deutscher würde ich einen Satz mit Partizip Perfekt Passiv ("*verschickt*") und "*sein*" nicht wirklich als Satz im Passiv verstehen, sondern als Beschreibung des **Zustandes** eines Objektes, der **durch die Handlung im Passiv** entstanden ist:

> Ihre Bestellung **wird** verschickt. => Passiv und "Action is happening"
>
> Ihre Bestellung **wurde** verschickt. => Passiv und "Action was happening in the past"
>
> Ihre Bestellung **ist** verschickt. => Description of the state of the object **now**
>
> Ihre Bestellung **war**(*) verschickt. => Description of the state of the object **in the past**

(*) Oder auch "*ist verschickt gewesen*" - je nach Dialekt oder Situation.

**Summary**

As you seem to speak English better than German (or at least many readers of this site do):

The combination of "*sein*" with the "Partizip Perfekt Passiv" of a word would be understood as description of the **state the object has after the action** by most Germans.

So:

> Ihre Bestellung **ist** verschickt.

... describes the state that the order ("*Bestellung*") has because the following has happened:

> Ihre Bestellung **wird** verschickt.

Answer (score 0):

'vom Blitz erschlagen werden' 
is firstly an infinitive, secondly an idiom (which you can't put within active form).

You could also say that the Blitz is currently striking the man 
'der Blitz erschlägt den Mann' 
but 'das sagt keiner' and also you may only use the past:

'Er/Sie/Es ist vom Blitz erschlagen worden'.
which is proper standard German opposed to dialects.

Comment: But it’s a passive infinitive.